# Issue understanding quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

In my linear algebra course my professor asked us this question in the problem sheet.

Consider the quadratic form $Q = 8x_1^2+2x_2^2+3x_3^3+8x_2x_3$. Find $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, such that $\alpha y_1^2 + \beta y_2^2 + \gamma y_3^2$. Is the standard form of $Q$.

My first issue is that I do not understand why Q is a quadratic form, given there is a cubic term in it. His notes are not very clear on this topic and online I have only found out how to represent a quadratic equation as $x^T M x$ where M is the coeffcient matrix. I cant see how to apply that here.

If anyone can explain this or send a link to a resource which does that would help a lot.

Comment: The cubic term is a misprint. We have $Q = 8x_1^2+2x_2^2+3x_2^3+8x_2x_3.$

Comment: @Fred: That's not much of a fix. :-D

Comment: OOps ! I mean: $Q = 8x_1^2+2x_2^2+3x_3^2+8x_2x_3.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite right that there *cannot* be a cubic term in a quadratic form -- for example, as written $Q(0,0,2)\ne 4Q(0,0,1)$, contradicting the definition.

It looks to me like the apparently cubic term is just a typo in the problem. It should be $x_3^2$, not $x_3^3$.

If you are to hand in written homework, I would simply start it with:

> I assume the form was supposed to be $8x_1^2+2x_2^2+3x_3^2+8x_2x_3$ ...

Comment: Ok that makes more sense, but I am a bit confused about the matrix of coefficients. Would it looks like $\begin{pmatrix} 8&0&0\\0&2&8\\0&8&3\end{pmatrix}$? I am aware it has to be symmetric but that is about it.

Comment: @VishalJain: No, that would produce $\cdots + 16x_2x_3$.  (Can you now see what to do?)

Comment: Ah, should be a 4, my comment was just about knowing which element to put what co efficient in, but doing the calculation sorted that out.